# URL Rewriting is Sending Requests for Non-Existent Pages to Main Page, Instead of 404 Page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to set up some URL rewriting using my .htaccess file. I'm a beginner, so bear with me! What I'm trying to do is reroute all requests from the root to the /main/ folder, since that's where I've got my CMS's files. For example, www.example.com/page should request www.example.com/main/page, but just show up in the browser as www.example.com/page. There are times, though, when I want to be able to access other folders, like when I post a dev or stage site at www.example.com/dev or www.example.com/stage. In these cases, we just can't have the request rerouted. Here's what I have so far:

```
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /main/ [L]
```

to rewrite root requests to /main, and:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main/$1 [L,QSA]
```

for all the other requests. It works fine, most of the time, but the problem is that if I type in www.example.com/something_that_doesnt_exist, it shows the main page (i.e. /main/), and keeps the URL in the address bar. If I take that same URI and add /main/, so in this case www.example.com/main/something_that_doesnt_exist it goes to the 404 page, which is the desirable result. How can I fix this so that www.example.com/something_that_doesnt_exist goes to the 404 page?

And, for bonus points, how to I get www.example.com/main to actually forward to www.example.com, so that if someone types it in it either goes to www.example.com (changing the URL in the address bar), or does a 404?

Comment: Are you using `ErrorDocument 404` in any of your .htaccess OR in Apache configs?

Comment: Nope! I'm using a CMS (Drupal), which sends things to the 404 page on its own. I'm implemented a nice 404 page in Drupal, so when you type in www.example.com/main/page_that_doesnt_exist, it goes correctly to the 404 page. I'll try it!

Comment: Ok, I tried adding the line `ErrorDocument 404 /main/404.html` to the .htaccess, and nothing happened. It's probably worth nothing that actually typing the address `www.example.com/main/404.html` brings up the 404 page, correctly.